# Can't do projectile stuff in pygame correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Trying to enable shooting projectiles with pygame. After I hit space button it shoots only 1 projectile, fps drops from 100 to ~30, player character can't move and does not react to button presses. After projectile stops being animated fps returns back to 100 and I can move&shoot up to 3 projectiles (as planned) but fps drops again and I can't move until the last projectile reaches the border.

I had a bullet image being loaded instead of drawing bullet before and thought that the case was in it. But the result didn't change. I also tried re-ordering `blit()` functions but nothing changed as well.

```py
class Game():
    # Some game stuff and functions
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_default = 800
        self.y_default = 600
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.x_default, self.y_default))
        #self.background = pygame.image.load('IMGs/BCK2.bmp').convert()         
        self.title = 'Title'
        self.fps = 100

class Projectile():
    # This class is supposed to make projectiles
    def __init__(self, x, y, speed_x=5, direction=1, width=10, height=10):
#       x&y - starting positions of projectiles
#       speed_x & speed_y - starting moving speeds of projectiles in # oX & oY
#       a - speed increase over time (cancelled for now)
#       direction - stays for its' name
#       Directions: [2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, -1, 7] starting from 0:00 and  moving towards the right side of the clock

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.speed_x = speed_x

        self.direction = direction

        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.img = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def move_projectile(self, x, speed_x, direction):

#       Moves stuff
#       For now direction works only in right-left (1 for right, -1 for left)

        x += speed_x * direction
        return x

while 1:
    if pygame.event.poll().type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()

    for pr in projectiles:
        if (pr.x >= -pr.width) and (pr.x <= Game().x_default):
            pr.x = pr.move_projectile(x=pr.x, speed_x=pr.speed_x, direction=pr.direction)
        else:
            projectiles.remove(pr)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

# ------------ oX moving --------------

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        P.x -= P.speed
        P.direction = -1

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        P.x += P.speed
        P.direction = 1

# ------------ Shooting ----------------

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if len(projectiles) < 3:
            if P.direction > 0:
                projectiles.append(Projectile(x=P.x + P.width, y=P.y + P.height//2, direction=1))
            else:
                projectiles.append(Projectile(x=P.x, y=P.y + P.height//2, direction=-1))

# ---------- The blitting process --------------

    G.screen.blit(G.background, (0, 0))
    G.screen.blit(Block1.img, (Block1.x, Block1.y))
    G.screen.blit(Block2.img, (Block2.x, Block2.y))
    for pr in projectiles:
        pygame.draw.rect(G.screen, (0, 0, 0), pr.img)
    G.screen.blit(P.img, (P.x, P.y))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(1000//G.fps)
```

Comment: (I edited everything correctly but it wanted me to press that CTRL+K, or it won't show my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How can i shoot a bullet with space bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687250/how-can-i-shoot-a-bullet-with-space-bar) and [How do I stop more than 1 bullet firing at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122492/how-do-i-stop-more-than-1-bullet-firing-at-once)

`keys[pygame.K_SPACE]` is `True` as long <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is hold. This means multiple bullets are continuously generated as long the key is hold.

If you want to create a single bullet, when <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is pressed, then use the `KEYDOWN` event (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)).
The event only occurs once, for each time when the key is pressed. e.g.:

```py
while 1:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:

                if len(projectiles) < 3:
                    if P.direction > 0:
                        projectiles.append(Projectile(x=P.x + P.width, y=P.y + P.height//2, direction=1))
                    else:
                        projectiles.append(Projectile(x=P.x, y=P.y + P.height//2, direction=-1))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # [...]
```