# How do you use sprite groups?

Tags: python, random, pygame

I get the error message `'Enemy' object has no attribute '_Sprite__g'` and I have no idea how to use the sprite groups. I'm trying to get them to spawn randomly across the x-axis only.

```
import pygame, os, random
pygame.init()
 
FPS=60

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((400,500))
pygame.display.set_caption('caption')

x=50
y=450
vel = 3
width = 20
height = 20

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 3
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0,0,0))
    def draw(self,SCREEN):
        SCREEN.blit(self.image, (self.x,self.y))
class B():
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius
        self.vel = vel
    def draw(self,SCREEN):
        pygame.draw.circle(SCREEN, self.color, (self.x,self.y),self.radius)
    
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20,20))
        self.x = random.randrange (0,400)
        self.y = 500
        self.speed = random.randrange(1,3)
    def draw (self,SCREEN):
        SCREEN.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
 
player = Player(x, y, width, height)
bullets = []
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
# Main loop
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x < 450 and bullet.x >0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
     
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if len(bullets)< 5:
            bullets.append(B(round(player.x + player.width //2), round(player.y + player.height//2),3, (0,0,0)))
            
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and player.y > 30 - player.width - player.vel:
        player.y -= player.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and player.y < 500 - player.width - player.vel:
        player.y += player.vel
 

    SCREEN.fill((190, 232, 220))
    player.draw(SCREEN)
    for bullet in bullets:
            bullet.draw(SCREEN)
    for i in range (8):
        e = Enemy()
        enemies.add(e)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the obects need to be derives from `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. The base class needs to be initialized as well. Use [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) to delegate to the base class constructor. e.g.:

```py
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        super().__init__() 
        # [...]
```

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The former delegates the to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group [...]

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

Therefore the Sprite class must have the attributes `.rect` and `.image`. However you don't need the `draw` method:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        super().__init__() 
        self.vel = 3
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
```

Create a transparent [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with the `SRCALPHA` flag and draw a circle on it:

```py
class B(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius, color):
        super().__init__() 
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius
        self.vel = vel
        self.image = pygame.Surface((self.radius * 2, self.radius * 2), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, (self.radius, self.radius), self.radius)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
```

Add [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)s for all sprites. [`add()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.add) the player, the enemies and bullets to the *Groups*:

```py
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

for i in range (8):
    e = Enemy()
    enemies.add(e)
    all_sprites.add(e)
```

Draw the *Sprites* in the `all_sprites` *Group* with [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw). Remove a *Sprite* (form all *Groups*) with [`kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill):

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    for bullet in bullets:
        if 0 < bullet.rect.y < 500:
            bullet.rect.y -= bullet.vel
        else:
            bullet.kill()

    # [...]

    all_sprites.draw(SCREEN)
```

Use the keyboard event instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()` to fire a bullet. See [How do I stop more than 1 bullet firing at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122492/how-do-i-stop-more-than-1-bullet-firing-at-once/60125448#60125448):

The collision of the enemies and bullets can be detected with [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). When the *doKill* arguments are set `True`, the sprites will be automatically removed:

```py
pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, enemies, True, True)
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame, os, random
pygame.init()
 
FPS=60

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((400,500))
pygame.display.set_caption('caption')

x=50
y=450
vel = 3
width = 20
height = 20

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        super().__init__() 
        self.vel = 3
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
   
class B(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius, color):
        super().__init__() 
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius
        self.vel = vel
        self.image = pygame.Surface((self.radius * 2, self.radius * 2), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, (self.radius, self.radius), self.radius)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
       
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20,20))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        y = random.randrange (0, 480)
        x = 400
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
        self.speed = random.randrange(1,3)
 
player = Player(x, y, width, height)

enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

# Main loop
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and len(bullets) < 5:
                bullet = B(player.rect.centerx, player.rect.centery, 3, (0,0,0))
                bullets.add(bullet)
                all_sprites.add(bullet)

    if len(enemies) < 8:
        e = Enemy()
        enemies.add(e)
        all_sprites.add(e)

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.rect.right < 500:
            bullet.rect.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullet.kill()
    for enemy in enemies:
        if enemy.rect.right > 0:
            enemy.rect.x -= enemy.speed
        else:
            enemy.kill()

    pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, enemies, True, True)
            
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()            
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and player.rect.top > player.vel:
        player.rect.y -= player.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and player.rect.bottom < 500 - player.vel:
        player.rect.y += player.vel
    
    SCREEN.fill((190, 232, 220))
    all_sprites.draw(SCREEN)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation:

"When subclassing the Sprite, be sure to call the base initializer before adding the Sprite to Groups."

So the first two lines of Enemy `__init__()` should be:

```
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
```

You also need to set a rect for the enemy:

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
self.rect.x = x
self.rect.y = y
```