# PyGame Movement and Shooting

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently trying to make my first game in Python. I just finished working on the movement but when my character jumps straight he just disappears. I am also trying to make my character shoot bullets but it wont show up. I don't know which part to change. I have not been able to figure this out on my own as I am still learning. Here is my code:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.constants import K_SPACE

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 480))
WinHeight = 480
WinWidth = 500

# player
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')



# Player movement
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]



# title
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
# background
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0   
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.standing = True
    
    def Draw(self, win):

        if not (self.standing):
            if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
                self.walkCount = 0
            if self.left:
                win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            if self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))

class Projectile(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x
        self. y = y
        self. radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius )
        
# functions
def redrawGameWindow():
    win.blit(bg,(0,0))
    man.Draw(win)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
man = Player(50, 400, 64, 64)
bullets = []

while running:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            break

    for bullet in bullets: 
        if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if man.left:
            facing = -1
        else: 
            facing = 1
        if len(bullets) > 5:
            bullets.append(Projectile(round(man.x + man.width //2)), round(man.y + man.height), 30,(138,43,226), facing)

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and man.x > man.vel:
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True 
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and man.x < WinWidth - man.vel - man.width:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False
    else:
        man.walkCount = 0
    if not (man.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            man.isJump = True
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.walkCount = 0
    else:
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.isJump = False
            man.jumpCount = 10
    redrawGameWindow()
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: I tried copying your complete example but I it still disappears.

Comment: I've added the full code to the answer. All you have to do is copy it.

Comment: I did copy the whole complete code and pasted it in my IDE. still, the character disappears when you just press "w" but it don't disappear when you press "w"+ "d"/"a".

Answer (score 0):

> [..] when my character jumps straight he just disappears.

You missed to initialize `man.jumpCount = 10`:

```py
while running:
    # [...]
 
    if not (man.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            man.isJump = True
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.walkCount = 0

            man.jumpCount = 10   # <-- this is missing in your code
    
    else:
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.isJump = False
            man.jumpCount = 10

    # [...]
```

---

> I am also trying to make my character shoot bullets but it wont show up.

The condition `len(bullets) > 5` is never fulfilled. It has to be `len(bullets) < 5`. In addition, the brackets are set incorrectly when you create a new `Projectile` object:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        facing = -1 if  man.left else 1
        if len(bullets) < 5:
            bullets.append(Projectile(round(man.x + man.width //2), round(man.y + man.height), 30,(138,43,226), facing))
```

If you want to fire just 1 `Projectile`, read [How do I stop more than 1 bullet firing at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122492/how-do-i-stop-more-than-1-bullet-firing-at-once/60125448#60125448).

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.constants import K_SPACE

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 480))
WinHeight = 480
WinWidth = 500

# player
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

# Player movement
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]

# title
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
# background
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0   
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.standing = True
    
    def Draw(self, win):

        if not (self.standing):
            if self.walkCount + 1 >= 27:
                self.walkCount = 0
            if self.left:
                win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            if self.right:
                win.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))

class Projectile(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x
        self. y = y
        self. radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius )
        
# functions
def redrawGameWindow():
    win.blit(bg,(0,0))
    man.Draw(win)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
man = Player(50, 400, 64, 64)
bullets = []

while running:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            break

    for bullet in bullets: 
        if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        facing = -1 if  man.left else 1
        if len(bullets) < 5:
            bullets.append(Projectile(round(man.x + man.width //2), round(man.y + man.height), 30,(138,43,226), facing))

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and man.x > man.vel:
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True 
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and man.x < WinWidth - man.vel - man.width:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False
    else:
        man.walkCount = 0
    
    if not (man.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            man.isJump = True
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.walkCount = 0
            man.jumpCount = 10
    else:
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.isJump = False
            man.jumpCount = 10
    redrawGameWindow()
```

Comment: @Gabriele I've added the complete example code the the answer.