# How to set the condition execution step

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, pygame

How to set the condition execution step so that the execution of the action when SPACE is pressed is not continuous?

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    print("spacebar is pressed")
    new_bullet = Bullet(screen, gun)
    bullets.add(new_bullet)
```

Answer (score 2):

See [How to get keyboard input in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044229/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-pygame/64494842#64494842) and [How do I stop more than 1 bullet firing at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122492/how-do-i-stop-more-than-1-bullet-firing-at-once/60125448#60125448). You have to use the keyboard events instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement.
The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

```py
# application loop
while run:

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame. K_SPACE:
                # [...]

    # [...]
```

---

An alternative method is to lock the key with a Boolean variable:

```py
space_pressed = False

# application loop
while run:

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if not space_pressed:
            space_pressed = True
            new_bullet = Bullet(screen, gun)
            bullets.add(new_bullet) 
    else:
        space_pressed = False
```